# Angular 4, разграничение прав доступа и функционала

Tags: html, typescript, аутентификация, angular-routing, angular4

Пытаюсь закрыть отдельные страницы для определенных ролей пользователей (или для незарегистрированных) следующим образом

```
{path: '', component: Test1Component, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], 
    children: [
        {path: 'test2', component: Test2Component, data: {title: 'Тест 2', roles: ['admin', 'user']}},
        {path: 'test3', component: Test3Component, data: {title: 'Тест 3', roles: ['admin']}},
        {path: 'test4', component: Test4Component, data: {title: 'Тест 4'}},
    ]
},
```

*auth-guard.ts:*

```
// canActivate единожды проверяет авторизован или нет

canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    let myRole = 'user'; // Получаем роль при инициализации приложения запросом на backend либо по своему усмотрению

    let roles = route.data['roles'] as Array<string>;
    if (!roles || roles.indexOf(myRole) != -1) return true;
   else {
        this.router.navigate(['']); //или на страницу авторизации
        return false;
    }
}
```

А как организовать добавление дополнительных функций для определенных ролей на общедоступные страницы, например, добавить кнопку редактирования новости для роли "Редактор"? Причем желательно с сохранением пути, т.е., например, не `./redactor/news`, а все тот же `./news`

**Update:**
Установил `angular2-permission`, подключил `Ng2Permission` в `app.module`; в компоненте, который проверяет доступ к целым страницам через `canActivate`, добавил

```
 import { PermissionService } from 'angular2-permission';
```

в конструктор добавил `private permissionService: PermissionService`
и при проверке ролей добавляю каждую `this.permissionService.add(role);`
В шаблоне, в котором нужно опционально показывать кусок кода для определенных ролей (для примера - роль `Admin`), добавил

```
<button (click)="doSomething() [hasPermission]="['Admin']" onAuthorizedPermission="enable" onUnauthorizedPermission="disable">
```

Свойство `hasPermission` не распознается:

> Can't bind to 'hasPermission' since it isn't a known property of
>   'button'

Пробовал дополнительно подключить `import { PermissionService } from 'angular2-permission';` в компоненте, который использует данный шаблон.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Функционал роутинга предполагает только управление доступом на основе ролей к определенным разделам сайта*,

но для управления отображением отдельных элементов нужных нам страниц лучше делать проверку по наличию нужной нам роли в массиве роли, массив можно возвращать через сервис, прописанный в конструкторе компонента.

1) **создаем сервис**, который при авторизации пользователя получает и сохраняет список ролей

2) **подписываемся в каждом из компонентов** на сервис в конструкторе компонента и получаем в некую переменную Roles перечень ролей

3) при отображаниии контролов, **ставми проверку** на наличие конкретной нужной нам роли в Roles

Готового решения на уровне фреймворка нет.

**Возможная реализация:**

Можно использовать директивы модуля Ng2Permission для того чтобы отображать или скрывать элемент.

Например, предположим что вы уже инициализировали разрешения для ролей Admin, Report и т.д. В примере ниже, кнопка удалить доступна когда определена роль Admin или добавлено разрешение. Подробнее тут: [PermissionService](https://github.com/JavadRasouli/ng2-permission/blob/master/doc/managing-permissions.md)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" 
  [hasPermission]="['Admin']"
  onAuthorizedPermission="enable"
  onUnauthorizedPermission="disable">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  Delete
</button>
```